# $window.on() not working in ES6 javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write some ES6 code that should allow me to do a show hide sticky footer.

My code runs up to a point, but then stops and i cannot fathom why. Am i using the arrow notation incorrectly? I have googled but am not sure i'm asking the right question so not finding anything of use.

```
const showFoot = {
    init: () => {
      showFoot.initShowFoot();
    },
    initShowFoot: () => {
      const $hero = $('.block--course .jumbotron');
      const $footer = $('.footer--bottom');
      console.log('were initing');
      $(window).on('scroll', () => {
        console.log('were scrolling');
        const yPos = window.pageYOffset;
        if ($footer.is(':visible') && yPos < ($hero.offset().top + $hero.outerHeight())) {
          $footer.fadeOut();
        }

        if (!$footer.is(':visible') && yPos > ($hero.offset().top + $hero.outerHeight())) {
          $footer.fadeIn();
        }
      });
    },
  };
```

And i get in the console only "were initing".

I do not get "were scrolling". I'm not able to see why this wont give me a console output when i scroll!

Any help would be really gratefully recieved.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that goes along with this? You might not actually be scrolling the window.

Comment: @evolutionxbox According to the jquery docs i can do:

"$( window ).scroll(function() {
  stuff;
});"

Comment: That's why I deleted my comment. I was incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see the delete before replying! Oh ok, so you think i may be scrolling a fixed element or something?

Comment: Oh you beauty! <body> had overflow-x: hidden; on it which was confusing things! Add your comment as an answer and i'll vote that up!

Comment: Ah. I'm glad it has been sorted. I'm happy if you would like to answer the question yourself.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, you go for it, you deserve points :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Although I'm still not sure entirely what the issue was, so I would be happier if you could resolve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the JS code was absolutely fine, but the `<body>` element had the css `overflow-x: hidden` on it so the scrolling wasn't being registered on `$(window)` but i guess would have been on `$('body')`.